# AngularJS directives attributes access from the controller

Tags: javascript, events, controller, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to access the attributes of a directive in the controller function. However, by the time I access it, it is undefined. I noticed that if I do a simple timer it works. Is there a way to execute code only after the directive and it's scopes are ready and set to be used?

I made a fiddle with it. Make sure your console is open. http://jsfiddle.net/paulocoelho/uKA2L/1/

Here is the code I am using in the fiddle:

```
<div ng-app="testApp" >
    <testcomponent text="hello!"></testcomponent>
</div>
```

```
var module = angular.module('testApp', [])
    .directive('testcomponent', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div><p>{{text}} This will run fine! </p></div>',
        scope: {
            text: '@text'
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            console.log($scope.text); // this will return undefined
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log($scope.text);    // this will return the actual value...
            }, 1000);
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            console.log($scope.text);
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log($scope.text);
            }, 1000);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What works is, if you set

```
scope.text = $attrs.text;
```

inside the linking and the controller functions. This will only work initially, as there is no 2way- databinding. You can use [$attrs.observe](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes) though.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JohannesJo/nm3FL/2/

Comment: This will fail linting. as `attrs.text` is unknown.

Comment: @DougChamberlain You can use JSDoc to go around that. Something like ``@param {string} attrs.text`` should solve your issue.

Answer (score 25):

In an isolated scope, a local scope property defined with '@' can not be accessed in the linking function.  As @remigio already mentioned, such local scope properties are `undefined` at that point.  $attrs.$observe() or $scope.$watch() must be used to asynchronously obtain the (interpolated) value.

If you are passing a constant value in the attribute, (i.e., no interpolation required, i.e., the attribute's value doesn't contain any {{}}s) there is no need for '@' or $observer or $watch.  You can use $attrs.*attribute_name* once as @hugo suggests, or if you are passing a number or a boolean and you want to get the proper type, you can use $scope.$eval($attrs.*attribute_name*) once.

If you use '=' to databind a local scope property to a parent scope property, the value of the property will be available in the linking function (no need for $observe or $watch or $eval).

Answer (score 10):

Instead using `$scope` to get directive attributes value, personally i prefer using `$attrs` for the `controller` function, or just `attrs` at 3rd parameter of the `link` function. I have no problem when get the attributes value from a `controller` by following code without timeout :

```
var module = angular.module('testApp', [])
    .directive('testcomponent', function () {
    return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div><p>{{text}} This will run fine! </p></div>',
    scope: {
        text: '@text'
    },
    controller: ['$scope','$attrs', function ($scope, $attrs) {
        console.log($attrs.text); // just call to the $attrs instead $scope and i got the actual value
        $scope.text = $attrs.text; //assign attribute to the scope
    }]
    };
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Since Angular 1.3, you can use `bindToController`. Here is a sample on how I use it. Here, I add the attribute to scope and then use `bindToController` to use that inside the controller:

```
var module = angular.module('testApp', [])
    .directive('testcomponent', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div><p>{{text}} This will run fine! </p></div>',
        scope: {
            text: '@text'
        },
        controller: function () {
            console.log(this.text);
        },
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true
    };
});
```

> Angular 1.3 introduces a new property to the directive definition
>   object called bindToController, which does exactly what it says. When
>   set to true in a directive with isolated scope that uses controllerAs,
>   the component’s properties are bound to the controller rather than to
>   the scope. That means, Angular makes sure that, when the controller is
>   instantiated, the initial values of the isolated scope bindings are
>   available on this, and future changes are also automatically
>   available.

Comment: @rjh Did you pass the `text` when calling the directive like this? `<testcomponent text="hello!"></testcomponent>`

Answer (score 1):

The link function is called before the $digest loop, at that moment scope variables are undefined. Look at [this chapter](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts) and [this other](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler) to understand how the link function operates. You only use the link function to define watches and/or behaviors for the directive, not to manipulate the model, this is done in controllers.

Comment: This is not all true. Scope variables are defined by the time the post-link function runs, and it is fine to manipulate your data model in a link function. Controllers are only needed on a directive if you plan to use it to communicate with another directive via the require property. The controller actually runs first, followed by the pre-link, going all the way down the dom tree to the leaves, then post-linking back up to the root. Refer to this thread for clarification. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615103/angular-directives-when-and-how-to-use-compile-controller-pre-link-and-post

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing this value from your directive to insert in your view using  a directive you can access this attribute using the $compile  api and  doing something like this

```
var string = "<div> " + scope.text + "</div>";
$compile(string)(scope, function(cloned, scope){
       element.append(cloned);
});
```