# ng-repeat in a directive does not update if the data changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have this problem on a larger project and I made the most simplistic example.

I have a controller that has some data in it. This data is fed into the directive and should be displayed using the native ng-repeat. However, when the directive-controller runs, it has not yet parsed the angular variable, thus not rendering the repeat.

How do I make it work so that the repeat works with that outside variable that needs pre-parsing?

Here is a fiddle. Make sure you have the console open as it shows there that it is undefined when the function runs, but defined 1 second later: http://jsfiddle.net/paulocoelho/xqLAs/2/

Here my JS:

```
var module = angular.module('testApp', [])
    .directive('test', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<p ng-repeat="x in sl">{{x.val}}</p>', // this wont work :(
        scope: {
            sl: '@sl'
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            console.log($attrs.sl);        // this will return undefined
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                console.log($attrs.sl);    // this will return the correct list
            },1000);
        }
    };
});

function sweetCtrl($scope){
    $scope.someList = 
    [
        {"val":"a"},
        {"val":"b"},
        {"val":"c"},
        {"val":"d"},
        {"val":"e"},
        {"val":"f"}
    ];
}
```

Here is my dom

```
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="sweetCtrl">
    <p>raw list: {{someList}}</p>
    <p>repeat list:</p>
    <test sl="{{someList}}"></test>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
There is was an error on my previous code where inputdata should read sl.

The fiddle with the solution is here: http://jsfiddle.net/paulocoelho/xqLAs/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use '@', the result is always a string.  If you change your template to show {{x}} instead of {{x.val}} you'll see what I mean.

To pass an object to your isolate scope, use '=':

```
<test sl="someList"></test>

template: '<p ng-repeat="x in sl">{{x.val}}</p>', // this will work :)
scope: {
     sl: '='
},
```

Also, as I (just now) explained in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15167819/215945), when '@' is used, you need to use $attrs.$observe or $scope.$watch() to asynchronously obtain the value (which will be a string).  With '=', you don't have to use $observe or $watch.

Comment: yeah, thats it. The whole @,=,& things confuse me. Thanks man :) I'll update my code with the new fiddle